# Access of register STM32 CAN communication

Tags: c, embedded

can you help  me to figure out what this line do :

```
while (hcan->Instance->MSR & CAN_MSR_INAK) != CAN_MSR_INAK)
```

Comment: @Garf365 Please try not to teach askers that leaving out practically all helpful detail will give reasonable answers. Also, please make an answer for answering. If answering well is not possible, then use a comment to ask about the needed details, or about whatever kept you from making an answer.

Comment: CAN controllers tend to have an initialization mode where you can set everything up. You have to enter it and then exit it, and when you do you have to wait for a flag. How this works for a specific CAN controller should be stated in the manual - you can't "figure it out" without RTFM.

Answer (score -1):

It is the common way to check flags or more precisliy - if bit is set in some register. In this particular example:

> INAK: Initialization acknowledge This bit is set by hardware and
>   indicates to the software that the CAN hardware is now in
>   initialization mode.

So you are basically wait in the infinite loop until CAN enter initialization mode.

BTW. I think you have way to much structures in your CAN configuration. If you use CMSIS macros package, it should look like this:

```
while((CAN->MSR & CAN_MSR_INAK) == 0);
```

Comment: OP is clearly using Cube, that `h` in `hcan` means it's a pointer to a CAN "handle", and that struct has the `Instance` member which is the actual pointer to the peripheral registers.

Comment: Probably ST wrote the "HAL" in that way to allow the same code to run for several CAN peripherals on the same MCU. Quite a common case when writing CAN drivers.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but it is not the "HAL" way. Is it from low layer libraries ? I haven't had an opportunity to test it yet. It doesn't look good :(